# SQL where clause sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

can someone please explain to me why my isn't working right?

```
select distinct campaignid
from(
select
day,
campaignid,
campaignname,
sum(campaign_impressions) as impressions,
sum(installs) as installs,
sum(revenue) as revenue
from bi.mobile_united_net t
where (campaignid in ( select TOP 14 distinct campaignid
                            from bi.mobile_united_net                    
                            where campaignid <> '3600961'
                            group by 1
                            order by sum(campaign_impressions) desc
                            ) 
        or  campaignid = '1433407')

group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2);
```

because of the WHERE i expect to get only 15 campaigns, but a get 408 campaigns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HONGt.png)

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: Can you please explain more? the first query seems to be fine

Comment: Is it not working right? Why don't you give us more information, do you get an error message, what is it, what do you expect?

Comment: Sub query must have an alias

Comment: please see my explanation above

Comment: Do you get campaigns returned that aren't in your top (14) list and aren't '1433407'?

Comment: yes i got campaigns returned that aren't in your top (14) list and aren't '1433407',, cant understand way

Answer (score 0):

This is grouped by `1,2,3` i.e `day,campaignid,campaignname,` so you will get one row for each combination of day and campaign (i.e. every day that one of your 15 campaigns happens on)

To get only 15 rows, you need to remove 'day' from your select, and group by to group by 'Campaign, campaignname` only

```
select distinct campaignid
from(
select
campaignid,
campaignname,
sum(campaign_impressions) as impressions,
sum(installs) as installs,
sum(revenue) as revenue
from bi.mobile_united_net t
where (campaignid in ( select TOP 14 distinct campaignid
                            from bi.mobile_united_net                    
                            where campaignid <> '3600961'
                            group by 1
                            order by sum(campaign_impressions) desc
                            ) 
        or  campaignid = '1433407')

group by campaignid,campaignname    
order by 1,2);
```

I also recommend using column names, instead of numbers, for grouping and ordering, it makes things much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: unfortunately, its is still not working, look at the output (image attached). you can see there 4408 rows

Comment: Try breaking it down then, what happens if you just run the inner query (TOP 14) then the next one out etc. etc.

Comment: Oooh, try limit 14 at the end of the subquery instead of top 14?

Comment: i tried and i saw its ok. i think there is a problem doing a subquery together with or condition. meaning if i have subquery in the WHERE clause i cant do: WHERE campaignid in (sub query results) or campaign  = '1462424'